# Regex to trim trailing space and new line

Tags: regex, newline, space

I have an extractor to extract string which sometimes spread over 2 lines.

**Regex :** `(?s)<h1 itemprop="name">(.+[\w\n\t])</h1>`

Examples:

**1) on 2 lines →**

```
<h1 itemprop="name">Hello-, World1234
</h1>
```

**Result :**

```
Hello-, World1234
Blank Line   -- I want to remove/trim this line
```

**2)　on 1 line →**

```
<h1 itemprop="name">Hello-, World1234</h1>
```

**Result :**

```
Hello-, World1234   -- This result is correct
```

Comment: let me know if the following answer helps you!
It will actually trim both heading and ending blank lines ;-)

Comment: A kitten dies when you use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: ^and kittens are cute, so please save them and do not parse HTML via regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
<h1 itemprop="name">\s*(([^<>\s\h]+\s*[^<>\h\s]+\h*)+)\s*</h1>
```

with a back reference to your first capturing group: `\1`

I have tested it on the following examples and it works file:

```
<h1 itemprop="name">
Hello-, 
World1234

</h1>

<h1 itemprop="name">Hello-, World1234

</h1>

<h1 itemprop="name">
Hello-, 


World1234

</h1>
```

it provides the following output:

1)

```
Hello-, 
World1234
```

2)

```
Hello-, World1234
```

3)

```
Hello-, 


World1234
```